# How to use AngularJS using CDN?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, typescript, visual-studio-cordova

Say that an app needs to be created using AngularJS with Cordova in Visual Studio, do I require anything else besides the Google CDN to use AngularJS?

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I notice that npm is usually used to install AngularJS, though if just a simple app needs to be created, could this be sufficient.

Code from: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading

Comment: What exactly is your question? Just wondering whether the documentation that you've linked to is lying?

Comment: I just want to know if using the CDN will be enough to create a basic application, such as one that contains a list or displays of users, because it seems that locally is the common method.

Answer (score 1):

That's all you need. I find installing angular locally is great for development, since I use developer tools to disable caching and I don't want to ping the CDN everytime I update a view, but for quick projects the CDN is fine.

Comment: Yeah, am limited on resources at the moment, so I just need a quick solution.